# Why is a user able to login and have a json web token is issued even though user has entered incorrect password?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, postman

1.below are the AuthRoutes.js , User.js , RequireAuth.js files with the code.

2.Ive tried changing the email to an invalid un-captured one  , and it does report the error "Invalid email or password" which is correct, however when the user enters the incorrect password for that user ,
3. a JSON web token is issued instead of posting the error invalid Email or password as indicated in the code.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', async (req,res)=>{
const {name,email,password} = req.body;
 
    try{
    const user = new User({name,email,password});
    await user.save();

     const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id},'MY_SECRET_KEY');
    res.send({token});
    } catch (err) {
    return res.status(422).send(err.message);
     }
  });

router.post('/signin', async (req, res) =>{
const { email, password} = req.body;
 
if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(422).send({error:'Must provide email and password  '})
}

const user = await User.findOne ({ email});
 if(!user) {
    return res.status(422).send ({error:'Invalid email or password'});
}

try{ 
await user.comparePassword(password);
const token = jwt.sign ({userId: user._id},'MY_SECRET_KEY');
res.send ({ token });
} catch (err){
    return res.status(422).send({error:'Invalid password or email'})
}
});

   
 

module.exports = router;
```

```js
const jwt = require ('jsonwebtoken');
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports = (req,res,next) =>{
 const {authorization} = req.headers.body;

//authorization === 'Bearer dfkndlkfgdkgmdlkgmdlkgdkfgmdlfkg(token)'

 if (!authorization)  {
     return res.status (401).send ({error:"You must be logged in"});
 }
const token = authorization.replace('Bearer ','');
jwt.verify(token, 'MY_SECRET_KEY', async (err, payload)=>{
    if (err){ 
    return res.status(401).send({error:'You must be logged in'});
    }

const {userId} = payload;
const user = await User.findById(userId);
req.user = user;
next();
});

};
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require ('bcrypt');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

name:{
    type:String,
    required: true,
},

email:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,

},

password:{
    type:String,
    required: true
}

});

userSchema.pre('save', function (next){

const user = this;
if(!user.isModified('password')){
    return next();
}

bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt) =>{
    if (err){
        return next (err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
            return next (err);
        }
        user.password = hash;
        next ();  
    
});

});
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword){

return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
bcrypt.compare (candidatePassword, this.password, (err,isMatch) => {
if (err){
return reject (err);
} else {

    return resolve(true);

}


    });

});
};
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `comparePassword` is returning a result that isn't checked for / caught.

Change your promise to:

```
return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
 bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, res) => {
  if (err){
   reject(err);
  } else {
   resolve(res);
  }
 });
});
```

And then your check to:

```
const result = await user.comparePassword(password);
if (!result) return res.status(422).send({error:'Incorrect email and/or password'});
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error : 'res already defined'. I then  changed the variable to 'isMatch ' and it still issues a token with an incorrect password

Comment: @WooqeyTrends Sorry, I put `res` instead `result`. Can you log what result is outputting during an incorrect and correct email/password entry? ie `console.log(result)`